# Using a variable from a VBScript in a ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, vbscript

I've been researching this for a majority of the day and can't find the answer. I am relatively new to stackoverflow. Is there a certain etiquette for asking a number of questions (I've asked three in the last few days)?

Anyways,

Here is the code in a codebehind file. It executes a script systeminfo.vbs, and that is working fine. But in the script I have some variables assigned.

```
Dim WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        WshShell.Run("wscript.exe c:\systeminfo.vbs")
```

---

vbscript

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each objOperatingSystem in colSettings 
dim osName 
osName = objOperatingSystem.Name
Wscript.Echo "OS Name: " & objOperatingSystem.Name
dim osVer
osVer = objOperatingSystem.Version
Wscript.Echo "Version: " & objOperatingSystem.Version
Wscript.Echo "Service Pack: " & _
    objOperatingSystem.ServicePackMajorVersion _
        & "." & objOperatingSystem.ServicePackMinorVersion
Wscript.Echo "OS Name: " & objOperatingSystem.SizeStoredInPagingFiles
Next
```

I want to use osName and osVer and put the values into a label on the ASP side.
I understand that osName and osVer are simple examples, but I just need to figure out the concept of putting variables from a VBScript into ASP. My client has multiple VBScripts they use on a daily basis and I need to automate those scripts and produce a report saying if it failed or not.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you output to a log file, read the log file, then clear the log file when you are done creating the report?

Comment: I don't see why not. Where should I look into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,

As a person new to Stack Overflow myself, I was happy to find this very comprehensive [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). See the 3rd question "Is there a limit on how many questions I can ask?" for an answer to your first inquiry.

Regarding the heart of your question, I agree with @Ramhound that using a log file to exchange information between your WSH/VBScript script and your ASP.NET page is a feasible approach.

What you need is the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. Here is a comprehensive [WSH reference](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2764) as a downloadable Windows help file.

***Hint**: as the download page advises at the bottom, to unblock the help page, 1) Right click on `script56.chm`, 2) Choose Properties, and 3) Click on "Unblock."*

You'll find an intro to `FileSystemObject` under the heading "Script Runtime."

**One more suggestion**: since you'll be running this script via ASP.NET in a multi-user environment, you may find you'll need to create a log file per user or per page access. If that is the case, you'll need to generate a temporary file name for each log file to avoid name collisions with other log files. To generate your temporary file, see `GetTempName` in the WSH reference.