# Copy the second latest modified file in folder : Help needed

Tags: vbscript

I ran into trouble where I need to do below task in VBScripting. Thanks in advance for helping out.

I want to copy second latest modified file from one folder to another location.

Eg: Source Folder "Final" will contain many subfolder in it. After running the script it should check for the second latest modified file in all the subfolders of "Final" and should copy the same to destination folder.

Comment: Please show us what you did yourself and where you ran into trouble. The way you ask it now is kind of ["This is my problem, deliver me the code please!"](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Answer (score 0):

@user, I believe this is the functionality that you are looking for. I addressed the heart of your problem in `Sub Find()`. Not guaranteed to be bug-free and I'm sure exception handling could be further improved.

**Tip**: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11371416/1497596) for information on downloading Microsoft's authoritative WSH reference as a Windows help file.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim oFF : Set oFF = New FileFinder
oFF.RootFolder = "C:\Source\Folder"  ' absolute or relative path
oFF.DestinationFolder = "C:\Copy\Folder\" ' must end with backslash

On Error Resume Next

'
' Find the newest and second-newest files.
'
oFF.Find

If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "Find error: " & Err.Description
    WScript.Quit(1)
Else
    WScript.Echo "Newest file: " & oFF.NewestFilePath
    WScript.Echo "Second-newest file: " & oFF.SecondNewestFilePath
End If

'
' Copy the second-newest file to the destination folder.
'
oFF.CopySecondNewestFileToDestination

If Err Then
    WScript.Echo "Copy error: " & Err.Description
    WScript.Quit(1)
Else
    WScript.Echo "'" & oFF.SecondNewestFilePath _
           & "' was copied to folder '" & oFF.DestinationFolder & "'."
End If

Set oFF = Nothing

' ============================================================

Class FileFinder

' Public RootFolder
Public NewestFilePath
Public NewestFileDate
Public SecondNewestFilePath
Public SecondNewestFileDate

Private mFso
Private mRootFolder
Private mDestinationFolder

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Me.SecondNewestFilePath = ""
    Me.SecondNewestFileDate = CDate("1970/01/01")
    Me.NewestFilePath = ""
    Me.NewestFileDate = DateAdd("s", 1, Me.SecondNewestFileDate)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mFso = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Let RootFolder(sValue)
    If Not mFso.FolderExists(sValue) Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "", _
           "Root folder '" & sValue & "' does not exist."
    End If

    mRootFolder = sValue
End Property

Public Property Get RootFolder()
    RootFolder = mRootFolder
End Property

Public Property Let DestinationFolder(sValue)
    If Not (Right(sValue, 1) = "\") Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "", _
           "Destination folder '" & sValue & "' must end with a backslash."
    End If

    If Not mFso.FolderExists(sValue) Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "", _
           "Destination folder '" & sValue & "' does not exist."
    End If

    mDestinationFolder = sValue
End Property

Public Property Get DestinationFolder()
    DestinationFolder = mDestinationFolder
End Property

Public Sub Find()
    Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = mFso.GetFolder(RootFolder)
    Dim oSubFolder, oFile

    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
        For Each oFile In oSubFolder.Files
            '
            ' File is newer than newest file.
            '
            If DateDiff("s", NewestFileDate, _
                        oFile.DateLastModified) > 0 Then
                SecondNewestFilePath = NewestFilePath
                SecondNewestFileDate = NewestFileDate
                NewestFilePath = oFile.Path
                NewestFileDate = oFile.DateLastModified

            '
            ' File is newer than second-newest file.
            '
            ElseIf DateDiff("s", SecondNewestFileDate, _
                            oFile.DateLastModified) > 0 Then
                SecondNewestFilePath = oFile.Path
                SecondNewestFileDate = oFile.DateLastModified
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub CopySecondNewestFileToDestination()
    mFso.CopyFile SecondNewestFilePath, DestinationFolder
End Sub

End Class
```